# Why am I getting null in the output of second class

Tags: null, output

I declare two classes FIRST class and Second Class. In `FIRST` class I declare the two variables `int A` and `String B`. I try to `print` the value of `A` and `B` in `SECOND` class. Both the classes are in same package. BUT, instead of getting value of `A` and `B`  the output of `A` and `B` is `null` in `SECOND` class

FIRST CLASS

```
public class FIRST {
    static int A;
    static String B;
    public static void main(String arg[])
    { 
        A=0;
        B=null;
        A=10;
        B=" "+A; //Converting integer to string
        System.out.print("VALUE OF A = "+A+"VALUE OF B = "+B);
    }//main
}
```

output OF FIRST CLASS

```
VALUE OF A = 10 VALUE OF B =10
```

SECOND CLASS

```
public class SECOND {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    { 
        FIRST o=new FIRST();
        System.out.print("VALUE OF A = "+o.A+" VALUE OF B = "+o.B);
    }//main
}
```

output OF SECOND  CLASS

```
VALUE OF A = 0 VALUE OF B =null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute `main()` method of the `SECOND` class (i.e. if your file is called `SECOND.java` which it should be, otherwise you'll get an error), `main()` of `FIRST` class doesn't get executed, and therefore `A` and `B` don't get assigned, therefore their values are `null`.